# How do I grant NETWORK SERVICE read permissions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently learning ASP.NET and I'm running into difficulties integrating SQL Server into ASP.NET.  I'm trying to grant NETWORK SERVICE read permission as follows:

4.NETWORK SERVICE must be granted Read permission to the top-level Visual Studio folder located in your user's Documents folder.  The Visual Studio folder will have different names depending on the version:  "Visual Studio 2005", "Visual Studio 2008", or "Visual Studio 2010".

5.NETWORK SERVICE must be granted both read and write permissions to your project's top-level project folder.  For example if your WAP project is called "MyCustomWebProject", then the folder "Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Projects\MyCustomWebProject" needs to have read and write access enabled for NETWORK SERVICE.  Or, if your webiste project is called "MyCustomWebProject", then the folder "Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Websites\MyCustomWebProject" needs to have read and write access enabled for NETWORK SERVICE.

6.NETWORK SERVICE must be granted both read and write permissions to the App_Data folder located within your web project's directory structure.

I've located the folders and accessed their properties but under security I do not have an entry for NETWORK SERVICE, how do I grant NETWORK SERVICE read and write permissions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have Admin access right click on the project folder --> Properties --> Security --> Edit --> Add --> Network Service as Name and give the permission.

Or if you are opening VS with admin access you probably may not need the access

Comment: Hi, I was able to add Network Service to permissions folder.  Thanks!  Turns out the issue was the connection string.  The site is working now!